# htaccess - Redirect to error page if user attempts direct file access?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website where the main directory contains a few files i don't want to be directly accessed using urls like this:

```
http://website.com/somefile1.ext1
http://website.com/somefile2.ext1
http://website.com/somefile1.ext2
http://website.com/somefile2.ext2
```

Currently they download if you enter the urls in a browser. Instead i would like to redirect them to a error page like this:

```
http://website.com/404
```

I found this snippet online but it doesn't work, it also doesn't redirect:

```
<Files ~ "\.(ext1)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

What would the correct .htaccess code be to do this task?

Edit:

I redirect site.com/script.php etc to site.com/script with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# turn on the mod_rewrite engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
# redirect to the php script with the requested filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this I didn't tried it for now,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ext\d$
RewriteRule ^ 404 [R=301]
```

Comment: I know my htaccess runs but that doesn't seem to work. It still downloads the files.

Comment: The 404 is a php file or do you have some other rules to handle it because above is working for me.

Comment: I edited my post above, i use a redirect function but it should only apply to .php files but perhaps it is interfering with the code. Shouldn't though.

Comment: Try my rule above your current rules

Comment: Maybe the rule is missing the `L` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<FilesMatch "somefile\.ext$">
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

You don't need to use the Order directive if you want to deny access from all.

Comment: I don't know, if this works, but adding an `ErrorDocument 403 /404.php` might show the desired error page.